# How to randomise a custom taxonomy tag cloud

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags, cloud

I have about 70 tags, I want to get 5 different random tags out of that 70 each time the page refreshes... this isn't working for me

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'electrician-perth', format => 'list', order => 'rand', number => '5', smallest => '10', largest => '10') ); ?>
```

All I get is the same 5 tags in alpha-numeric order each time I refresh my page?

Thanks heaps,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

Valid orderby fields for [`wp_tag_cloud`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud) are `name` or `count`.

Comment: Maybe **the lack** of `orderby` was the issue? Also in the OP sample code, doesn't the parameters need single quotes?

Comment: I think I read the question wrong, my answer doesn't make sense. I don't know, it was early.